# Modern and free LDAP virtual directory server

Tags: gratis, active-directory, ldap, directories

I'm looking for something like [Penrose](https://fedorahosted.org/penrose/) or [MyVD](http://myvd.sourceforge.net/). My requirements:

- virtual directory accesible by LDAP v3 protocol and supporting bind and search methods;
- gets its data from remote LDAP v3 servers one of which is Active Directory;
- connection is enrypted using SSL/TLS;
- can join entries with the same UID from diff
  erent LDAP sources;
- has some ACL capabilites, so I can set which tree branches can be queried by which user/client;
- no anonymous access;
- it has logging capabilites;
- it can work in read-only mode (it doesn't have to support any other mode)
- it's free (gratis), doesn't have to be open-source;
- it's fairly modern (e.g. I don't need to install old Java 1.5 JRE like it is with Penrose VD Studio) and its development isn't halted;
- there is active community of users around it;
- it can be run on Linux;

What I am trying to achieve? We have some web applications which I want to authenticate its users using LDAP. These applications can use only one LDAP server, I cannot configure them to use more LDAP servers. Moreover, some of my LDAP servers aren't accessible from outside of organization (e.g. Active Directory), so I need something that will join data from my internal and external LDAP servers and present it to the client web app.

Comment: There is plenty of Free Virtual LDAP Open Source tools, please specify exactly what you trying to achieve.

Comment: @SolutionSurfers, I've updated my question.

Comment: Check into the free online zFlex Software LDAP Server. I think it may meet most of your requirements. http://www.zflexsoftware.com/index.php/pages/free-online-ldap

Comment: @TonyM, zFlex LDAP is free only for testing and development purposes.